# I wrote a query to word count a user, could someone please give some feedback?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Sometimes I would like use word count to describe someone's contribution, so, I wrote a query (https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1206589/word-count-a-user) to do the job:

```
DECLARE @total_count int, @post_id int, @post_body nvarchar(max);  

SET @total_count = 0;

DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT id, Body
FROM posts 
WHERE posts.OwnerUserId = 9872;

OPEN vendor_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor   
INTO @post_id, @post_body
PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('  id   | count | total count')
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count int;
    SELECT @count = (LEN(@post_body ) - LEN(replace(@post_body , ' ', '')))
    SELECT @total_count = @total_count + @count
    PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('%6d | %5d | %d', @post_id, @count, @total_count)
    FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor
    INTO @post_id, @post_body
END
```

I guess this is not a question, neither a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/238517/219846). Just a tool query sharing, and gather some feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably do that in one go, without the cursor and variables.

Use the STRING_SPLIT function, that returns a table from a text based on a split char.

Here is the simplified [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1206619).

```
SELECT id [Post Link]
     , count(*) [# words]
     , SUM (count(*)) OVER (ORDER BY Id) [total]
FROM posts 
cross apply string_split(posts.body,' ') words
WHERE posts.OwnerUserId = 9872
group by id
order by id
```

It is worth mentioning that the Body of the Posts table contains the rendered HTML of the post. As such it might have more "words" due to the added tags like `<p>`. To stay closer to the actual text that was posted, find the latest revision of the Post in the PostHistory table (PostHistoryTypeId in ( 2, 5, 8)) and then split the Text column. I leave that as an exercise for the reader

Remember that we have a site called CodeReview.se that are happy to take SQL query improvement/review requests. They also have a [stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) tag for questions that are about SEDE.

Comment: Thank you so much. Btw, what does "words" do in the "cross apply string_split ..." line?

Comment: @andrewngdl it is the alias for the table, just as I could do `posts p` then p would be the alias for the posts table, allowing me to do p.id.